# Issue with Return from Recursive Staticmethod in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, static-methods

I'm just getting back into Python after a long break. I'm running this code in 2.* Python but was using print() syntax. Don't think that should be an issue.

I don't understand while the final print statement in the function returns the correct answer but the "return" doesn't actually work and returns None/NoneType. Is this something I don't get about recursion in Python or recursion with staticmethods? Thanks. Code example below.

```
import json

class DictHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def get_info2(data, *args):
        k = args[0]
        print(data)
        if (len(args) > 1): 
            try:
                ndata = data[k]
                a = list(args)
                a.pop(0)
                DictHelper.get_info2(ndata, *tuple(a))
            except:
                print("Error with key = " + args[0])
        else:
            print("the value for data[" + k + "] is ")
            print(data[k]) # this works
            return data[k]

def demo():
    json_str = """{ "Payload": { "humidity": { "sensor-part-number": "X12345" }}}"""
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    v = DictHelper.get_info2(data, 'Payload', "humidity", "sensor-part-number")
    print(v) # this returns None

demo()
```

Comment: You need to write `return DictHelper.get_info2(ndata, *tuple(a))`

Comment: Let me incorporate those two changes. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're correct. Brain burp moment there. I'll revise my previous statement.

Comment: If you would like `print` to behave like a function is python 2, use the `__future__` module: `from __future__  print_function`

Comment: Barmar, do you want to post that as answer to get credit? Not sure how this dupe question thing works anymore. Its been while since I used the site.